# file.setSharing() giving me Exception: Invalid argument: OWNER

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to check how permissions work in `Google Apps Script` , so I am trying to create a File for each set of Permissions listed in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/permission?hl=en

```
function main () {


    // CREATING A FILE WITH CERTAIN PERMISSIONS
    // -------------------------------------------
    var folderRef = DriveApp.getFolderById('root');
    folderRef = folderRef.getFoldersByName('toarchive').next();
    var fileRef = folderRef.createFile("NONE" , "Some text" , "text/plain");

    fileRef.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.NONE);
    //-------------------------------------------
    // eof eof eof eof eof eof eof eof eof eof eof


    // CREATING A FILE WITH CERTAIN PERMISSIONS
    // -------------------------------------------
    var folderRef = DriveApp.getFolderById('root');
    folderRef = folderRef.getFoldersByName('toarchive').next();
    var fileRef = folderRef.createFile("OWNER" , "Some text" , "text/plain");

    fileRef.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.OWNER);
    //-------------------------------------------
    // eof eof eof eof eof eof eof eof eof eof eof

    // CREATING A FILE WITH CERTAIN PERMISSIONS
    // -------------------------------------------
    var folderRef = DriveApp.getFolderById('root');
    folderRef = folderRef.getFoldersByName('toarchive').next();
    var fileRef = folderRef.createFile("ORGANIZER" , "Some text" , "text/plain");

    fileRef.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.ORGANIZER);
    //-------------------------------------------
    // eof eof eof eof eof eof eof eof eof eof eof

(...)

}
```

The issue is that it gives me an Error when Running the Script

```
Error Exception: Invalid argument: OWNER
```

Answer (score 2):

Based from the Enum Permission documentation, using the "OWNER" property (along with  "ORGANIZER" and "FILE_ORGANIZER") will have its value returned but passing it to File.setSharing() is an exception and therefore cannot be used this way.

I have tried the other properties:

- "NONE" may be passed to File.setSharing().
- "VIEW", "EDIT", and "COMMENT" will result in an "access denied" error which will only be fixed when the google account used has an admin role.

Here is the part of your script that I used to test the properties:

```
function permissionTest() {
  // CREATING A FILE WITH CERTAIN PERMISSIONS
  // -------------------------------------------
  var folderRef = DriveApp.getFolderById('1ZKYjo70s51TANG9Zu3eojTkJpe3-SyOd'); //test folder ID
  folderRef = folderRef.getFoldersByName('toArchive').next();
  var fileRef = folderRef.createFile("EDITABLE", "Some text", "text/plain");

  fileRef.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT); //changed "EDIT" to other properties to test
  //-------------------------------------------
  // eof eof eof eof eof eof eof eof eof eof eof
}
```

Here is the sample of your script being run in a google account without an admin role:

[image: non-admin-sample]

Here is the sample of your script being run in a google account with an admin role:
[image: sample]

Comment: Please edit your answer and include the cod and not images of the code.  OP can not copy your code if its an image.

Comment: My bad. I just wanted to show the difference between using a google account without an admin role and with an admin role. I already updated my answer. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am the sole user of this account and I am executing the Script under this account. Seems that I am not an admin of my own account. How do I become an admin?